# How to store content of text area from nicEdit with formatted text in a database

Tags: nicedit

I am using the nicEdit editor for a text area, which may have text, image, links and other formated text. I don't know what datatype to use in a MySQL database to store its content.

If there is any other way to handle this stuff, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save the data in a [`text`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) column. I think it is a good idea to encode the data before saving. For example, save it as base64 (if you don't have to search in the content), or as url encoded string.

If the images are uploaded to the server, you have to save the images on the webserver too. A few options are:

1. Use `Blob` fields (binary large objects) to save the images
2. Convert the images to an base64 string directly for use in the html code.
3. Save the images on the file system, not the database

In my tests, options 1 and 2 create a lot of data. So it is better to save the images on outside the database.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Hi, how can i read the image? I am using Java...when i submit the form, using the textarea name i get the html. How to get the image from it?